# python: calling c++ with numpy array input

Tags: python, c++, cython, ctypes

I have the following c++ code and I want to import it into python.

```
#include "test.h"
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

double vec_sub(const std::vector<double> &u, const std::vector<double> &v, int ui, int vj)
{
    double max{0.0};
    double d{0.0};
    
    for(int i = 0; i < u.size(); i++)
    {
        d = std::fabs(u[i] - v[i]);
        if(i == ui || i == vj)
        {
            d = 0.0;
        }
        if(d > max)
        {
            max = d;
        }

    }
    return max;
}

std::vector< std::vector<double> > chebyshev_distance(const std::vector< std::vector<double> > &matrix )
{
    unsigned long row{matrix[0].size()}, col{matrix[0].size()};

    std::vector<std::vector<double> > dist( row, std::vector<double> (col, 0));  
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < row; j++)
        {
            dist[i][j] = vec_sub(matrix[i], matrix[j], i, j);
            dist[j][i] = dist[i][j];
        }
    }
    return dist;
}
```

For the function "chebyshev_distance", lets assume that the corresponding function in python is the same "chebyshev_distance"

```
dat = np.array(...) # n by n 2D array
dist = chebyshev_distance(dat)
```

In the above code, the input is a numpy array. Does the python automatically convert the vector in c into numpy in python? If not, how do I change the c++ code?

Comment: Assuming you're using Cython (based on the tags) then `vector<vector>` well be automatically converted to a list of list. This is obviously inefficient. Nested vectors are a fairly awful way to define a 2D array though.

Comment: Using `std::vector` in interfaces for interaction with other languages isn't a very good choice: The memory layout isn't  known (and even is compiler-dependent). An interface similar to Python's buffer protocol: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html would be a better option.

Comment: Assuming you're using `ctypes` (based on the tags), `ctypes` doesn't understand C++ types.  It is "C" types after all.  You would need a `double* data, size_t size` C-compatible interface, and could use `numpy` to manage the arrays from Python.